Lock behavior on mass delete queries with postgresql
I would like to know how Postgresql handles locks on bulk deletions.
My goal is to avoid deadlocks during my opertations.
At the moment, we only do insertions and updates (using batched INSERT ON CONFLICT). Deadlocks are avoided by properly sorting our rows during our saves. Therefore in case of updates (which could cause deadlocks), there is no risk of cross locking data.
However, now, I also need to run deletions on large bulks of data.
I would like to know if a single delete query impacting multiple rows could lead to deadllocks with INSERT ON CONFLICT queries running in parallel.
I assume this all comes down to locking atomicity. Are all rows impacted by a delete query locked atomically?

All statements lock rows one after the other, in the order that they find them. So any two statements that modify or delete the same two rows in a different order can deadlock with each other.
You will get the best performance if none of the statements modify the same rows, but if they do, they should modify the rows in the same order. There is no direct way to influence the order in which rows are deleted, but you can use the trick described in the PostgreSQL documentation:
WITH delete_batch AS (
  SELECT l.ctid FROM user_logs AS l
    WHERE l.status = 'archived'
    ORDER BY l.creation_date
    FOR UPDATE
    LIMIT 10000
)
DELETE FROM user_logs AS dl
  USING delete_batch AS del
  WHERE dl.ctid = del.ctid;


Thanks for your answer.
So if I understand correctly, what I need to do is using a "SELECT FOR UPDATE" statement to control the locking order of the rows I am considering to delete before deleting them.

By the way, do you know what the behavior is with INSERT ON CONFLICT statements?
Are locks taken in the order values are provided?
In the example below, is there a guarantee row with ctid 1 is locked before row with ctid 2?
INSERT INTO user_logs (ctid, status, creation_date)
VALUES
(1, 'archived', now()),
(2, 'archived', now())
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT uk_user_logs
DO UPDATE SET
status = EXCLUDED.status

Yes, you SELECT ... FOR UPDATE first. The row lock order of the INSERT statement will depend on the execution plan (use EXPLAIN). You can probably use similar tricks to force a certain order.

When running the code below, I get this explain result (see next comment).
I cannot figure out if any sort order is guaranteed.
create table public.user_logs
(
    id          smallint generated by default as identity
        constraint pk_user_logs
            primary key,
    status        varchar,
    creation_date timestamp(0)
);

EXPLAIN
INSERT INTO user_logs (id, status, creation_date)
VALUES (1, 'archived 2', now()),
       (2, 'archived 3', now())
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pk_user_logs DO UPDATE SET status = EXCLUDED.status


Insert on user_logs  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=0 width=0)
Conflict Resolution: UPDATE
Conflict Arbiter Indexes: pk_user_logs
->  Values Scan on "VALUES"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=42)

That should be in VALUES order. But please, don't use comments for stuff like that.
